# "Do something" as soon as user opens Chrome browser [Chrome extension development]

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Considering I want to track the time the Chrome browser is open: Do I need the user to manually click a button, e.g. "Start tracking", or is there a way to do this *as soon as* the browser was opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is consider adding a background page to your Chrome Extension (They are also called event pages, more info here : http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html). The way these work is that Chrome instantiates this once per session when the browser starts. You could start a timer there and keep a track of time the user spends on your browser that way. 
HTH!

Comment: Thanks Trunal! But this means I need to set the background to persistent: true, which is not recommended by Google. Right?

Comment: well, its a guideline for being a good citizen. They say that since they dont want to you consume resources when you dont need them. In this case though, there's a legitimate reason for making persistent:true.